# How to model this criss cross shape

Tags: modeling, modifiers, wireframe

I've tried using the wirefram mod. But the wireframe isn't flat.

I've tried making the grid on a cylinder > removing faces> converting to curve >curve panel increasing extrude and depth but this leaves verticle lines from the original cylinder

I feel like it's something easy and I'm just stuck on the wrong method to get it done

[image]

Comment: Can you share an image of what you have tried in solid mode? or share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: oh you want the wireframe part encircled in blue to be flat?

Comment: Yes and I was able to get that effect with a bevel modifier. The problem then was at the intersection point it was no long right angles

Answer (score 0):

[image]Lets say we want that shape on this cylinder: [image]

The first thing we should do is spawn in a 2D plane and delete one side of vertices so we are just left with an edge, like so:

[image]

We would then set a screw modifier on the new edge we just created and set the axis to X in this case so that we get this cylinder looking shape. [image]

then adjust the screw value and iteration value until the object roughly matches the length of your handle as well as your desired length. Here's what I have now
[image]

you can then go into edit mode with this object and adjust the thickness by adjust one of the vertices like so:

[image]
[image]

Adjust to how you see fit.

Now align this object with your target object, in your case the sword handle and set a shrinkwrap modifier onto the criss-cross shape while setting its target as your sword handle. Then apply a solidify modifier and adjust so you get something like this (you may need to adjust screw and iteration values if it doesnt look right.)
[image]

And for the final step, duplicate this new criss cross and then with the object selected type (S Z -1) ((In this case we used the Z axis)) and then slightly adjust the new object as well as increasing its solidity to solve any clipping. Your final result should be like this:
[image]
You can then add as many criss cross shapes as you need as well as adjusting modifiers to get your desired effect.

Comment: Thank you but I think the design on the picture is slightly different. If you look at the side where the light green gems are. It looks like there is no criss cross on the side. I'm assuming the back would look like the front. But the sides just seem to go around around. Almost like a ring

Comment: Well in that case you would apply all the modifiers, join the two objects together and then cut it in half. After that youd apply a mirror modifier on the Z axis, turn clipping on and then extrude the edges down until they meet as shown in the new image. I also forgot to mention to add subdivision modifier to make it look better if needed.